# Disabling double shift functionality in pycharm 2021.1

Tags: pycharm, popup, shift

I've started a project using pycharm 2021.1 on a virtual desktop (VDI). The VDI translates a shift held for 0.5s as a double shift, and this infuriating search box pops up.

pycharm seems to move how to disable this every new version. All the solutions I've found have missing menu items.

Does anybody know how to do it in pycharm 2021.1.1
I have no option to change my pycharm version. I have to sort it out in that version.

BTW the project is a 5G base station. It's quite complex.

Comment: There is a search function in all Jetbrains IDE when u ALT+CTRL+S

Comment: ALT+CTRL+S takes me to settings. Advanced options one of the methods is missing. Typing shift into search bring me nowhere useful

Answer (score 0):

Go in your settings with ALT+CTRL+S then go in advanced settings and turn on "Disable double modifier key shortcuts"

Comment: There are no "advanced settings" in "settings" in 2021.1 That's why I asked about a specific version. They move this functionality every version

Comment: Use the search bar on the settings, and search double, until you find it.

Comment: I have already tried searching double, shift, double shift in settings

Comment: You are using a quite old pycharm version, use the double shift then search registry open it and search `ide.suppress.double.click.handle` then enable it if it's there, else i don't know how to help you on this version.

Comment: Afraid that didn't work either, but thanks for your efforts